# Number created with constructor does not have its value as a property, unline String from constructor

Tags: javascript

Why do I have to access the `[[PrimitiveValue]]` property of a **Number** created with a constructor and not a String:

```
var n1 = 0;
var n2 = new Number(0);
console.log(n1);
console.dir(n2); //only the [[PrimitiveValue]] contains 0:"t", 1:"e", 2:"s", 3:"t"
console.log(n1 == n2)  //true

var s1 = "test";
var s2 = new String("test");
console.log(s1);
console.dir(s2); //[PrimitiveValue]] contains "test", but there are also the 4 propeties 
console.log(s1 == s2); //true
```

http://jsbin.com/AkOTUSA/1/

Also how do I access that value?: `console.log(s2[[PrimitiveValue]]);` throws an error.

Comment: I'm not getting what you're getting for `console.dir(n2);`

Comment: you can use a `n2.valueOf();` to get a primitive value... or `+n2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, the way to access objects' primitive value is with `X.prototype.valueOf`, where `X` is the object type.

So, for instance:

```
var n1 = 0;
var n2 = new Number(0);
console.log(n2.valueOf()); // logs 0
console.log(n2.valueOf() === n1); // logs true
```

This is true also for strings, and for other types of objects. Note that custom objects will not implement this in the same way, or indeed possibly at all.

---

You also ask why `n1 == n2` in your question. First, note that `n1 === n2` returns `false`.

`===` means "strictly equal". That is to say, they are equal, without any type conversion necessary.

`==` tests for equality, but allows for type conversion if necessary. From [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators):

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the operands, then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible;

Since `n1` is a number primitive, `n2` is converted to a number primitive before the comparison is done. This number primitive is `0`, so they are equal.

Comment: but why does `n1 == n2` without needing `n2.valueOf() == n1.valueOf()`?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `n2.valueOf()`. The ECMAScript [spec says about `valueOf`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4.4):

> Returns this Number value.

where "this Number value" is [described previously](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.7.4):

> ...the phrase "this Number value" refers to... the Number value represented by this Number object, that is, the value of the `[[PrimitiveValue]]` internal property of this Number object...

The properties in the EMCAScript spec marked with `[[ ]]` are not real, progammatically-accessible properties; they are so-called ["internal" properties](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6.2) that help describe the behavior of the specification:

> This specification uses various internal properties to define the semantics of object values. These internal properties are not part of the ECMAScript language. They are defined by this specification purely for expository purposes. An implementation of ECMAScript must behave as if it produced and operated upon internal properties in the manner described here. The names of internal properties are enclosed in double square brackets [[ ]].